# content in middle but image wider

Tags: html, css

How to set css so that the content was in the middle but one div like this:

EDIT:

```
+----------------------------+
|         MONITOR            |
|    
|    +----------------+      |
|    |    CONTENT     |      |
|    +-----------------------|---------------+
|    |                       |               |
|    |    IMAGE TO THE RIGHT | REST OF IMAGE |
|    +----------------+------|---------------+
|    |                |      |
|    |    CONTENT     |      |
|    |   MIDDLE OF    |      |
|    |    SCREEN      |      |
|    |                |      |
|    |                |      |
+----------------------------+
```

EDIT 2:

I do not want the horizontal scroll. Image hiding must simply hide behind right side.

How to do it?

Comment: so you mean the image should "leak" out? is the image in the container in the middle? or is it a sibling of the content?

Comment: `position:absolute; left:20%; right:20%;  width:60%;` for the content.

Comment: I edited post. image "extends" content. Content has a width in px.

Comment: >"Image hiding must simply hide behind right side." Do you mean to say you want the image cropped to the width of `.content` so that the "rest of image" is not shown?

Comment: Yes, image hide. Like huge background image on body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.content {
    width: 400px; /* whatever fixed width */
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

You can see the live demo here: http://dabblet.com/gist/2730694

Comment: I notice now. I do not want the horizontal scroll. Image hiding must simply hide behind right side.

Comment: Then you should add overflow:hidden on the body. I've updated the demo - check it again http://dabblet.com/gist/2730694